# I'm a yii2 developer i want to change the color of string

Tags: yii2

I want to change the color of the return value I want 'paid' with green background and 'pending'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWVDV.png) with red, I'm trying to change the color but I did not. I will attach the code and a screenshot below. Kindly tell me the solution to solve this issue.Im trying but  failed

### View

```
       <?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\pjax;

 
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\BillSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Bills';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="bill-index">




    <?php echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
   
     <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    
        'columns' => [
            

            'id',
            [    'header'=> 'Name',
                'attribute'=>'consumer_id',
                'value'=>'consumerId.allottee_name',
            ],

      

            'cnic',
          
           
               'fileNo.file_no',
           


            'total_bill',
[
            'header' => 'Status',
'attribute' => 'status',
'value' => function ($model, $widget) {
    if($model->status == 1){
        return ("Paid");
    } else{
        return ("Pending");
    }
},

            ],
           
      
         
        ],
    ]); ?>
     
</div>
```

### Model

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
 
/** 
 * This is the model class for table "bill".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $consumer_id
 * @property int $total_months_conservancy
 * @property int $water_arrears
 * @property string $water_remarks
 * @property int $conservancy_amount
 * @property int $total_water_and_conservancy_amount
 * @property int $tinure
 * @property int $dues_amount
 * @property int $per_month_charges
 * @property int $no_of_months
 * @property int $total_amount_of_current_months
 * @property int $advanced_pay
 * @property int $arrears

* @property int $water_bill 
 * @property int $arrears_period
 * @property int $total_bill
 * @property int $after_due_date_charges
 * @property int $total_after_due_date
 * @property int $balance_arears
 * @property string $remarks
 * @property int $conservancy_charges_per_month

 * @property string $billing_months
 * @property string $issue_date
 * @property string $due_date 
  * @property string $cnic
 * @property string $reference_no
 */
class Bill extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $file;
    public $file_no;
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'bill';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['consumer_id','file_no', 'water_arrears',  'conservancy_amount', 'dues_amount',  'arrears', 'arrears_period', 'total_bill', 'after_due_date_charges', 'total_after_due_date', 'issue_date', 'due_date','status'], 'required'],
            [['file'],'file'],
            [['consumer_id', 'total_months_conservancy', 'water_arrears', 'conservancy_amount', 'total_water_and_conservancy_amount', 'tinure', 'dues_amount', 'per_month_charges', 'no_of_months', 'total_amount_of_current_months', 'advanced_pay', 'arrears', 'arrears_period', 'total_bill', 'after_due_date_charges', 'total_after_due_date', 'balance_arears','payment','debit','sector'], 'integer'],
            [['issue_date', 'water_bill', 'due_date','created_on','updated_on',  'advanced_pay',  'tinure','billing_months','email','cnic','cat_status'], 'safe'],
            [['water_remarks','document'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
            [['remarks'], 'string', 'max' => 350],
            [['billing_months'], 'string', 'max' => 25],
            [['reference_no'], 'string', 'max' => 13],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'Bill No',
            'consumer_id' => 'Name',
            'cnic'=>'CNIC',
            'email'=>'Email',
            'total_months_conservancy' => 'Total Months Conservancy',
            'water_arrears' => 'Water Arrears',
            'water_remarks' => 'Water Remarks',
            'conservancy_amount' => 'Conservancy Amount',
            'total_water_and_conservancy_amount' => 'Total Water And Conservancy Amount',
            'tinure' => 'Tinure',
            'sector' => 'Sector',
            'dues_amount' => 'Dues Amount',
            'per_month_charges' => 'Per Month Charges',
            'no_of_months' => 'No Of Months',
            'total_amount_of_current_months' => 'Total Amount Of Current Months',
            'advanced_pay' => 'Advanced Pay',
            'debit' => 'debit Pay',
            'arrears' => 'Arrears',
             'water_bill' => 'water_bill',
            'arrears_period' => 'Arrears Period',
            'total_bill' => 'Total Bill',
            'Status'=>'Status',
            'after_due_date_charges' => 'After Due Date Charges',
            'total_after_due_date' => 'Total After Due Date',
            'balance_arears' => 'Balance Arears',
            'remarks' => 'Remarks',
            'conservancy_charges_per_month' => 'Conservancy Charges Per Month',
            'billing_months' => 'Tenure',
            'issue_date' => 'Issue Date',
            'due_date' => 'Due Date',
            'reference_no' => 'Reference No',
            'cat_status'=> 'Status',
        ];
    }

   
            public function getconsumerId()
            {
                return $this->hasOne(Plot::className(),['id' => 'consumer_id']);
            }

            public function getfileNo()
            {
                return $this->hasOne(Plot::className(),['id' => 'consumer_id']);
            }
          public function getsectorName()
                {
                    return $this->hasOne(Sectors::className(),['id' => 'sector']);
                }
               


   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowOptions` https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview#$rowOptions-detail to provide html attributes on a per row basis.

```php
<?= \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
  // ...
  'rowOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
    return ['class' => $model->status === 1 ? 'table-success' : 'table-danger'];
  },
  // ...
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to make function in model for this kind of code. I am guessing that you are using bootstrap.

```
'header' => 'Status',
'attribute' => 'status',
'value' => function ($model, $widget) {
    if($model->status == 1){
        return "<span class=\"badge badge-success\">Paid</span>";
    } else{
        return "<span class=\"badge badge-danger\">Pending</span>";
    }
},
'format' => 'raw', //'format' => 'html',
```

Comment: it print the value as it is  "<span class=\"badge badge-success\">Paid</span>"

Comment: how to make  function?

Comment: @checkit you were using `gridview`? and added `'format' => 'raw',`?

Comment: yeah im using gridview

Comment: insane skull i'm attaching the view file kindly check

Comment: @checkit you didn't added `'format' => 'raw'` yet.  check last line of answer

Comment: @checkit check the given answer and update your code again if does not work